# How To Change Shortcut For Edge Loop

Tags: edges

What category is the Edge Loop shortcut in? Ctrl+R is awkward and hurts my wrist and I want to change it. Thanks.

Comment: Go to `Preferences` > `Keymap` Search by Name and you will find it.

Comment: I already tried that. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: I figured it out. I typed "Edge Loop" and got nothing. I typed "Edge" or "Loop" and the options came up.